# ¿ Cómo ejecutar código si x clip de animación está ejecutándose? Unity

Tags: animación, unity2d

Me gustaría que alguien me ayudase con un problema que me ha surgido trabajando en Unity. Quiero, dentro del código del script, que cuando el personaje esté en cierto Clip, por ejemplo el clip Andar, haga o deje de hacer algo según ciertas condiciones, la cuestión está en como llamar al animador en el "if" para saber si estoy en "Andar", "Saltar" o lo que sea. Es decir si -- if (ani=="Andar") {…} -- . ¿Cómo hay que inicializar el componente Animation para tal fin? Gracias  de antemano.

Comment: Estas utilizando el componente animation o animator?

Comment: Estoy usando el Animator para devolver una condición y así gestionar las animaciones en Animator, pero me gustaría saber como, dentro de un script, saber qué animación se está ejecutando y en función de esta realizar una acción u otra. Supongo que se hace desde Animation.    private Rigidbody2D rb2D; //caracteristicas de un cuerpo (objeto)
    private Animator anim; // caracteristicas animacion
    

void FixedUpdate()
    { //Aquí realizar la operación  if (ani……….. realizar x acción.....    Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres comprobar la animación con su nombre:

```
anim_Animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Nombre animacion")
```